# SSRS Group Subtotal and Total

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to get the subtotal for WO Total Cost but where that WO Number appears multiple time in the Division group I don't want to add them together.  I only want the cost for WO Total to appear once in the report for each division.  As it is now the work order number 40321 has a WO Total Cost of $362.24 and because it appears for each laborer it is added in the total represented in the green total line.  Can anyone tell me how to prevent summing WO Total Cost where the WO Number appears more than once in a Division group?

[image: SSRS Report Screenshot]

Thanks for the reply Alan.  Here is a screenshot of the design view in Report Builder.  So, what I'd like to see is a summing of only the WO Total cost once for each report for each WO Number.  The WO Total cost represents all costs (Equipment, Labor, and Material) for a given work order. So, at it stands now, the report is summing work order 40321 three times and giving us an incorrect total.

I've grouped the report by Division so we can see costs for a particular division for a given time period.  I've also grouped the report by Person Labor so we can see how much a particular laborer is costing us for a given period of time.

What I don't know is how to do is prevent the report from summing the WO Total cost where the WO Number appears multiple times in the results for a given division. 
[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the report design including the rowgroups below the main design and also show what rowgroup each of the affected cells are in. Also, based on your example, can you say what the expected number(s) would be and why. I think I understand it but without more info it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Hi Alan, I've edited my question to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you will be able to do this directly in the report design without some convoluted custom code. Other people maybe will have more inspiration but I can't see how to do it. You cannot even look for unique values to sum as it's possible that 2 WO numbers could have the same cost.

Without knowing what your dataset/database tables look like I can't offer much more but here are some approaches I might consider if I was doing this, both mean doing the work in SQL.

**Option 1 **
I would consider calculating this in your query in a new column which should be fairly simple. Each row would end up with the total amount for the AssetGroup. So, if you had 20 records for AssetGroup A and 10 records for AssetGroup B than all the 'A' records would have the same 'AssetGroupTotalWOAmount' value and all the 'B' records would have the same 'AssetGroupTotalWOAmount' value.

Then in your report you can simply use `=FIRST(Fields!AssetGroupTotalWOAmount.Value)` to get the correct number. This will get the first value within the scope of the expression, so your case within the ASSETGROUP row group.

**Option 2 **
Create a separate dataset with just the amounts you need, with a single record per AssetGroup . So probably just two columns, AssetGroup and AssetGroupTotalWOAmount

In the report you could then use a `LOOKUP` to get the correct value.